Trying to get the list of courseWork of Classroom API with javascript (error "the required parameter courseId is empty")
I am trying to get the list of courseWork for a specific course. I access an iteration of the courses and when the appropriate course arrives successfully I use the following code to get the courseWork list:
await gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.list(idcourse, 
  {}).then(function(response2) 
{                            
 });

The error I get is that "the required parameter courseId is empty".
The response2 object is undefined.
idcourse is a string that is obtained in the iteration and I have verified that it is a valid and correct string.
I have tried other options like:
 await gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.list( 
          {courseId : idcourse}).then(function(response2) 
        {                            
         });

Siempre arroja el mismo error.

Make sure idcourse is a valid string and contains the correct courseId. You can add a console.log(idcourse) before calling the list method to verify.

Thanks! I use before  if (courses[i].id == idcourse) {}. I'm sure that is correct. I try and the result is: The value of idcourse is 714339014312

Finally it funcionned with this code:
 await gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.list({courseId: idcourse }).then(function(data){
    var courseWorks = data.result.courseWork;
}

The response "data" show results into "result", that it contain a array with all taks in the course with id "idcourse".
Thanks you!
